# Tomcat usurping 404 not found error, returns 500 instead

Tags: java, tomcat, wicket

**ObHumor**: Apparently my "not found" page cannot be found. :-)

I have a Wicket app that has a custom 404 Not Found page. Used to work fine when we ran under Glassfish, and it continues to work fine when I use Jetty and `Start.java`.

But when running under Tomcat 7.0.19 the app never shows its 404 page- Tomcat seems to "eat" the bad request, and returns a 500 to the client. I see the following in the logs:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0 - - [30/Sep/2011:16:35:57 -0400] "GET /bad-link HTTP/1.1" 500 5
```

I have the following in my `web.xml`:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404</location>
</error-page>
```

And indeed if I visit that page directly (/404), I see my 404 page. But if I request "/bad-link", I get Tomcat's 500 response.

Here is my tomcat `server.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" 
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443"/>
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->           
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the 
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">         
    --> 
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->        

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false"/>

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

My catalina.properties is vanilla except for the following line which I have added:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true
```

This allows %2F encoded slashes to appear in the URLs.

**Edit**: in case it matters: my app is mounted at the root context (i.e. deployed as ROOT.war).

Comment: Show us the rest of the tomcat config. It sure looks like some webapp thinks it owns /bad-link. Perhaps you forgot to clean out some of the toys that sometimes show up in the webapps dir?

Comment: Also crank logging up to debug to see if there's a reason for the internal server error.

Comment: I just cranked up tomcat logging to FINE (including the LifecycleBase), and unfortunately I'm still not seeing anything suspicious.

Comment: Could you show the definition of the Wicket filter in the web.xml. (Oh... just realized how old this is. FTR: The filter dispatcher needs to capture ERROR and REQUEST for Wicket error pages to work correctly.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you added this to your web.xml also?

```
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>wicket.filter.my</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```